# Side by side different lists html5

Tags: css, html

I need to put three different lists side by side: an unordered list, an ordered list, and a description list
I have tried a ton of different things but so far no float inline or inline block is working, unless i am doing it wrong and someone would like to explain the correct way to use these. The way I tried it was

```
       #schedule {
} 
#schedule ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
    display: inline-block;
}
#schedule ol {
    list-style-type: none; 
    display: inline-block;
}
#schedule dl {
    list-style-type: none; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

as the css for

```
    <aside id="schedule">
            <h2>Favourite Teachers</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Steve Sutherland</li>
                <li>Steve Sutherland</li>
                <li>Steve Sutherland</li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Favourite Classes</h2>
            <ol>
                <li>Web Programming</li>
                <li>Tim's</li>
                <li>The Den</li>
            </ol>
            <h2>Favourite lessons</h2>
            <dl>
                <dt>First Webpage</dt>
                    <dd>Got me hooked</dd>
                <dt>Images and videos</dt>
                    <dd>Endless joke possibilites</dd>
            </dl>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them in `div` and `float` the div's.

```
<div class="first">
<ul>...</ul>
</div>

<div class="second">
<ol>...</ol>
</div>

<div class="third">
<dl>...</dl>
</div>
```

In CSS :

```
.first, .second, .third{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cmmabu8n/

Comment: I retract that it worked for the most part but how do i stop the overflow?

Comment: You can still try it out, you'll see if it fits. I don't know what you're actual design is like, if there's not enough room in the `aside` for them to fit in the same row then I don't know what's the point of asking this question.